# Shell Script : shortcut add and assignment += : command not found

Tags: shell, scripting, addition, shortcut, assignment-operator

Using Mac Terminal and Shell Script

Trying to do Shortcut of add and assignment operator like

```
SumVar=1

$(( SumVar += 5 ))

echo $SumVar
```

Getting error :

> Error: line 3: 5: command not found

What is the correct syntax of this ?

Comment: You seem to have gratuitously edited the numbers so they no longer agree with the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for incrementing the variable is correct, but you are using it in a context where Bash wants a command, and it complains that the result of the increment (`4`) is not a recognized command.

The `let` keyword is your friend.

```
let SumVar+=4
```

Or better yet just leave out the dollar sign (thanks @chepner);

```
(( SumVar += 4 ))
```

Comment: `((...))` is preferred to `let`.

Comment: I saw your edit suggestion to change the number to 5 but really, what's with changing the numbers after the fact? Your question still isn't consistent (the error message should say 6, not 5).

Answer (score 2):

When you use a substitution like this, `bash` will try to execute a command of the substituted name/value. You can use this instead:

```
(( Sumvar += 5 ))
```

Or if you really insist on using substitution here, you can use it as an argument to the `:` command:

```
: $(( Sumvar += 5 ))
```